# How to write an android application without java

Tags: android, c++, android-studio

I am going to port my c/c++ application that does ray tracing. I need all the power of the device, so I don't want to use java, I would like to use only c/c++ to write the application

I can roughly run c/c++ code, but I can't output the image. How can I implement framebuffer access on android via c/c++?

The power of my phone is enough(port through unity is successful), but the same code but in java doesn't work even at 5 fps. It's very slow.

I would like to use android studio to write an application, Visual studio and eclipse do not work on my system

Comment: The snarky answer to the headline alone is Kotlin. The NDK likely provides what you want.

Comment: Why do you think changing to c++ would give you such a speedup?  The culprit is likely a defect in your Java implementation.   You don't get magical speedups by switching to c++.

Comment: Getting started links:- [Android NDK](https://developer.android.com/ndk); [OpenGL ES 1.0 - 3.2](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/stable_apis); [Sample: Teapot](https://developer.android.com/ndk/samples/sample_teapot); [Sample: native-activity](https://developer.android.com/ndk/samples/sample_na) .  Having read these if you have a specific question please read [ask] with a [mcve].

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.